# Can't set RecyclerView inside CardView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[image]

I'm trying to put a `RecyclerView` inside a `CardView` and create items dynamically.

Obviously, in `XML`, `RecyclerView` is set inside `CardView tag`, but as you can see picture, `RecyclerView` item is created outside `CardView`.

(`RecyclerView's items` are the parts expressed as `kg` and `set` in the photo. And `CardView` is also an item of another `RecyclerView`.)

What's the problem?

***XML***

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/workout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TEST"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/light_blue_400"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll1">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                style="@style/RoutineButtonStyle"
                android:text="DELETE"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                style="@style/RoutineButtonStyle"
                android:text="ADD"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: You asked this question yesterday. No again. Probably improve your explanation of the error. Should "Set" and "kg" be inside the cardView or not? Describe which elements are wrong. With arrows on your image. Only with the main elements and a piece of code, noone could help you. If it is increased I'm sure there will be a solution I can provide you

Comment: sorry. Yesterday's post was deleted because there was no response at all.

And the article has been slightly edited.

Comment: I will help you soon, if I'm at home. Have an idea how to solve that.

Comment: okay. I will wait. Thanks.

Comment: Use LayoutInspector to check the bounds of the views. Also, your nested LinearLayouts are a waste - you can align your "TEST", Divider, and buttons directly within the ConstraintLayout - that's kinda the point of it.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @dominicoder 
I tried using LayoutInspector but couldn't find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `Activity` of your add/delete `CardView`:

```
      //Item List if you want to add one or more Items
        private List<MyItem> myItems = new ArrayList<>();


        private Adapter smallCardAdapter;


        private int size;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);

            //Creates a new Object in the Adapter.class
            smallCardAdapter = new Adapter();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(smallCardAdapter);
            CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            MaterialButton delete = findViewById(R.id.delete);
            MaterialButton add = findViewById(R.id.add);


            //Add onClickListener
            add.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                try {
                size = myItems.size();

                //if the value is 0, a new item is created
                //if you want to delete the card after 0 than you have to change the value to 0
                if(size == 0){
                    //Creates a new Object in the MyItem.class
                    myItems.add(new MyItem("Set","1kg"));
                }else{
                    MyItem myItem = myItems.get(0);


                    //Replace kg with "" to make a Integer
                    String secondString = myItem.getSecondString().replace("kg","");
                    Integer value = Integer.valueOf(secondString);
                    value++;
                    myItem.setSecondString(value+"kg");
                    myItems.set(0,myItem);

                }

                updateAdapter();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.w("MainActivity","Add Button OnClickListener");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            });


            //Delete onClickListener
            delete.setOnClickListener(v->{

                try {
                    size = myItems.size();
                    //If the value is 0 then canceled to avoid errors
                    if(size == 0){
                        return;
                    }

                    MyItem myItem = myItems.get(0);

                    //Replace kg with "" to make a Integer
                    String secondString = myItem.getSecondString().replace("kg","");
                    Integer value = Integer.valueOf(secondString);

                    //if the value is one or lower
                    if(value <= 1){
                        //The card will deleted after updateAdapter();
                        myItems.clear();
                    }else{
                        value--;
                        myItem.setSecondString(value+"kg");
                        myItems.set(0,myItem);
                    }
                    updateAdapter();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.w("MainActivity","Delete Button OnClickListener");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });


        }
        private void updateAdapter(){
            try {
                smallCardAdapter.setItems(myItems);
        }catch (Exception e){
                Log.w("MainActivity","updateAdapter");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

---

The custom Item called `MyItem`:

```
public class MyItem {

    String firstString;
    String secondString;

    public MyItem(String firstString,String secondString){
        this.firstString = firstString;
        this.secondString = secondString;
    }
    public String getFirstString() {
        return firstString;
    }

    public void setFirstString(String firstString) {
        this.firstString = firstString;
    }

    public String getSecondString() {
        return secondString;
    }



       public void setSecondString(String secondString) {
            this.secondString = secondString;
        }
    }
```

---

The `Adapter.java` creates a `smallCard`:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.SmallCardHolder> {



    private List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SmallCardHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //                                     I created a new smallcard for the CardView
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.smallcard, parent, false);
        SmallCardHolder smallCardHolder = new SmallCardHolder(itemView);
        return smallCardHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SmallCardHolder holder, int position) {

        //get the current item of the position
        MyItem myItem = items.get(position);

        String firstString = myItem.getFirstString();
        String secondString = myItem.getSecondString();

        holder.textViewSet.setText(firstString);
        holder.textViewkg.setText(secondString);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void setItems(List <MyItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    class SmallCardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        //Here are the TextView's of the smallcard (smallcard.xml)
        private TextView textViewSet;
        private TextView textViewkg;

        public SmallCardHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
            textViewkg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.kg);

        }
    }
}
```

---

Create a new layout with name called `smallcard.xml` for the `Adapter.java`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/set"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Set"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="kg"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/set"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

In your `XML` you have to give the `CardView` a name. I called it `cardView`. Here is the code `android:id="@+id/cardView"`

Result:

[image: Result]

You will find more information as comments in the code.

Comment: First of all, based on your answer, I've only used xml code.

But the result is the same.. What's the problem?

Comment: If you use only the xml that's logical. We added the "Set" and "kg" on an item that will  keep in the Recycler View. You want to be it in there right? Or only on the CardView? It should only be once there or will you at the values multiple times?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say one thing. When a `CardView item` is created, subitems with `kg` and `set` must have one first.

As the OP mentioned, `CardView` is also an item of recyclerview.